# plist or storage of dictionaries

Tags: iphone, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

What is the best way to store a number of dictionaries in iOS?

I want to be able to save a new dictionary to the users phone. Is there a way to iterate through the dictionaries in a plist or should it be a plist consisting of an array of dictionaries?

Is plist the best way to do this or is there another way?

How would the array of dictionaries be loaded from the plist and stored in the app? I am trying to load a current plist into an array, but get null values.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a dictionary out using `writeToFile:atomically`. If you write them into a directory you can loop through the files in that directory. But don't forget to put them in a writable directory.

Other ideas include saving the files out and saving the file name in the shared preferences.

However, if I were in your position, I would checkout [nanostore](http://code.google.com/p/nanostore/). I think it will meet all your needs without being as bogged down as core data.